# tqdm show progress for a generator I know the length of

Tags: python, generator, tqdm

I'm looping over a large file that I know the length of, but am processing lazily since it's too large to fit in memory. I'd like to be able to use tqdm to keep track of my progress through the file, but since it can't get the total number of examples out of the generator I'm using, the only thing it shows is the estimated iterations/second. Is there any way to tell tqdm how many elements it's going to be looping over total so I can get some of the other statistics?

Comment: Pass the length to the optional `total` argument of `tqdm`.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can pass the **length** to the argument **total** to make it work.

Example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

length = 1000000
generator = (3 * n for n in range(length))  # just doing something random
for n in tqdm(generator, total=length):
    pass
```

Comment: What is the case for using an iterator with a generator inside (with __len__ implemented) and the case against, compared to just specifying the `total` parameter for tqdm?

Answer (score 1):

If you provide an iterator that implements `__len__()`, tqdm will call that function to obtain the total number of iterations.

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

class File:
    def __init__(self):
        self.line = 0
    
    def __len__(self):
        return 5
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.line += 1
        if self.line > len(self):
            raise StopIteration()
        return self.line

for _ in tqdm(File()):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Otherwise, you can provide the total number of iterations in the `total` parameter.

```
class File:
    def __init__(self):
        self.line = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.line += 1
        if self.line > 5:
            raise StopIteration()
        return self.line

for _ in tqdm(File(), total=5):
    time.sleep(1)
```