# How to track progress with nlp.pipe function of spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, pipe, spacy, tracking

I'm coding with Python and Spacy.
I want to track the progress of the execution of `nlp.pipe(sentences)` because it lasts a lot.
How to do that?

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentences = [...]
docs = nlp.pipe(sentences, n_process=8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

```
from tqdm import tqdm

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentences = [...]
for doc in tqdm(nlp.pipe(sentences, n_process=8)):
    ... do stuff ...
```

Comment: `7465it [00:37, 197.51it/s] ` I don't have progress bar. Do you know why? Do you tested it with `nlp.pipe`?

Comment: Please read the tqdm documentation. `nlp.pipe` returns a generator, so tqdm doesn't know how long it is. You can do `tqdm(nlp.pipe(sentences), total=len(sentences))`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985993/tqdm-show-progress-for-a-generator-i-know-the-length-of